# How can i make border for active class nav-item in bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want to change some styles in `nav-item`. I made another style sheet and in that I made this code. The problem is that in Internet Explorer it works fine but in Firefox nothing changes. How can I make some changes in `nav-link active`?

For example, I want to have a border-bottom when the nav is active.

```html
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light py-md-5">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

        <div class="justify-content-end  collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">ABOUT US</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">SERVICES</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">TEAM</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">CLIENTS</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the custom styles?

Answer (score 2):

add this css in your custom style

```
.nav-item.active
{
  border-bottom:2px solid #f00;
}
```

```css
.nav-item.active
{
  border-bottom:2px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light py-md-5">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="justify-content-end  collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT US</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">SERVICES</a>
      </li>  
       <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">TEAM</a>
      </li>  
       <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">CLIENTS</a>
      </li>  
       <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
      </li>  
    </ul>
  </div>  
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.nav-link').click(function() {
  $('.nav-link').removeClass("active");
  $('li.nav-item.active').removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light py-md-5">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="justify-content-end  collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT US</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">SERVICES</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">TEAM</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">CLIENTS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```